# Separate for - loops to one alternating one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some Python code and I needed to change the logic of the code when I realized I can't come to a neat and *efficient* code solution.

So my first version is the following:

```
#set ranges
range_a=150  
range_b=178  
range_c=20  

#add elements  
for x in range(0, range_a):
    # ...do something...
    add_element_a()

for y in range(0, range_b):
    # ...do something...
    add_element_b()

for z in range(0, range_c):
    # ...do something...
    add_element_c()
```

As you can see I was adding the elements by type, first for type_a, then for type_b, and in the end for type_c. Now I would like to create a while-loop or something in order to add them alternating.

For example, we start by adding one from type_a and then one from type_b  and etc. and we do it until we reach a range for a certain type, and then we continue for the rest of them.

I know it could be seen as a basic problem, but I am looking for an efficient solution?

Here is the second version which I find too complicated and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it:

```
filled_a = False
filled_b = False
filled_c = False

while(!(filled_a & filled_b & filled_c) == True)):
 if (counter_a < range_a):
     add_element_a()
     counter_a++
     if(counter_a==range_a): filled_a=True
 if (counter_b < range_b):
     add_element_b()
     counter_b++
     if(counter_b==range_b): filled_b=True
 if (counter_c < range_c):
     add_element_a()
     counter_c++
     if(counter_c==range_c): filled_c=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate according to the greatest range and check which range still wasn't exhausted:

```py
#set ranges
range_a=150  
range_b=178  
range_c=20  

#add elements  
for i in range(max(range_a, range_b, range_c)):
    if i < range_a:
        add_element_a()
    if i < range_b:
        add_element_b()
    if i < range_c:
        add_element_c()
```

Answer (score 1):

Such one of sulutions you can try this:

```
class RangeCounter:
    def __init__(self, range_type):
        self.range_type = range_type

    def add_element(self):
        # implement your addition logic here
        pass

range_a= RangeCounter(150)  
range_b= RangeCounter(178)  
range_c= RangeCounter(20)
range_list = [range_a, range_b, range_c]

for range_type in range_list:
    range_type.add_element()
```

Comment: This will call `add_element` once per range. Where does the actual range number comes to play?